# Meteor app using mongodb bulk operation throwing timed out exception

Tags: mongodb, meteor, bulkupdate

I am trying to insert a bunch of objects (around 14000 of them) but I always end up getting timed out error.

I begin with setting my timers like this:

```
  Mongo.setConnectionOptions({
    mongos: {
      socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: 1800000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 1800000,
        socketTimeoutMS: 1800000,
      },
    },
  });
```

I then create bulk operations:

```
console.log(Mongo._connectionOptions.mongos.socketOptions);

  const bulk = IntegrityTest.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  const session = IntegrityTest.insert({
    // fields...
  });

  checkResult.flagged.forEach(function (item) {
    bulk.find({ _id: session }).update({
      $addToSet: {
        // fields...
      }
    });
  });

  bulk.find({ _id: session }).update({ $set: { finishedAt: new Date() } });
  bulk.execute({ w: "majority", wtimeout: 1800000 });
```

The above log prints what was initially set:

> { keepAlive: 1800000,
>     connectTimeoutMS: 1800000,
>     socketTimeoutMS: 1800000 }

Still the timeout error is always thrown after 5 minutes:

> C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_6\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:313
>   throw(ex);
>
> MongoError: connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:3003 timed out
>
> at Object.Future.wait
>   (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_6\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:449:15)
>   at [object
>   Object]._.extend._nextObject (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1024:47)
>   at [object Object]._.extend.forEach (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1058:22)
>   at [object Object]._.extend.map (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1068:10)
>   at [object Object]._.extend.fetch (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1092:17)
>   at [object Object].Cursor.(anonymous function) [as fetch] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:907:44) 
>   at [object Object].MongoConnection.findOne (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:814:56) 
>   at Object. (packages\matb33_collection-hooks.js:658:16)
>   at Object.collection.(anonymous function) [as findOne] (packages\matb33_collection-hooks.js:137:21)
>   at [object Object]._.extend.findOne (packages/mongo/collection.js:332:29)
>
> at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\2.2.16_1\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
>   at Socket. (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\2.2.16_1\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:184:20)
>   at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
>   at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>   at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7) at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:333:8)
>   at _runOnTimeout (timers.js:537:11) 
>   at _makeTimerTimeout (timers.js:528:3)
>   at Timer.unrefTimeout (timers.js:597:5)

Comment: Have you tried any of the bulk operations meteor packages instead of doing manually (eg. mikowals:batch-insert, udondan:bulk-collection-update, etc.). I've had good success with them.

Comment: Can you make sure that those socketOptions are being honored?  Also, did you check the status of mongodb when you receive the timeout error?

Comment: Also since bulk.update is an asynchronous function you probably need to use wrapAsync or bindEnvironment.